# How to prevent jQuery Droppable from accepting certain Draggable?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm creating a page with "groups" of droppable widgets, and each draggable can only be dropped on one group of droppables.

I was able to achieve this by the following code:

```
$("div.droppable").droppable({
    //accept: ".draggable",
    accept: function (draggable) {
        if ($(this).attr("question_id") != null) {
            if ($(this).attr("question_id") == draggable.attr("question_id")) return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

However, now I'm having a little trouble. After dropping, I was not able to move the draggable around droppables in the same group as I could before. I could drop it on a droppable once, move it to another, but I couldn't move it back to the first droppable.

Does anyone know what could have happened? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what failed in your code. I created this [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7kWM/) that is working as expected. As seen in this test case, I am using [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve the question ID.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great, it works. I'm using <div id="xxx" question_id="yyy">...</div>. Not sure why it doesn't work in this way.

Comment: Good to hear! Could be that you are using an underline as a delimiter. Also, when dealing with custom attributes use the data prefix, since that's defined by the HTML5 standard and easily accessed by jQuery's `.data` function. Read this [article by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) on the topic.

Comment: No I'm using underscores in both draggable and droppable events. And thanks for the help and the link.